# Display N numbers of uid from firestore i am new to flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to retrive all the users from firestore and display it and perform some action how can i achieve it

````
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading Data');
        return ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
                // Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['uid']),
                title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['fname']),
                onTap: () {})
          ],
        );
      },
    );```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading Data');
        List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshotDocuments = snapshot.data.documents;
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshotDocuments.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
           return ListTile(
                // Text(snapshotDocuments.documents[index]['uid']),
                title: Text(ssnapshotDocuments.documents[index]['fname']),
                onTap: () {})
             }
         
        );
      },
    );
```

You can read more about ListView.builder and ListView class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html).
What the code above does is that it uses the `itemCount` (it calls `itemBuilder` that many times) which is equal to the length of `snapshotDocuments.length`. it passes the index to the `itemBuilder` function and you can use that index to loop through your documents and show the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since this stream will return a list of all documents you can use ListView.builder widget which builds list according to some length i.e in this scenario it will build list according to length of users present in database.

```
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading Data');
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length;
                itemBuilder: (context,index){
                  return ListTile(
                    // Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['uid']),
                      title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['fname']),
                      onTap: () {});
                }
              );
            },
);
```